# GreaseMonkey Continuous Integration

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, greasemonkey

I've created a greasemonkey script, it started out small with a few images as resources and slowly it became bigger.

Until now I stored the script and the images on a onedrive, obtaining the embedded link for each file (and for the auto-update url) and hard coding it into the script.

What's changed now is that another person will need to review code changes and the files will need to be stored in his location. So for updating the version I'll need to send him the new script file, and for each resource I'll need to send him the resource, wait for him to give me the embedded links, add those in the code and only then give him the new script version. 
You can imagine the overhead.

I'm trying to think of a solution for this problem.
If he stored it all in a server, SVN could be a solution, and each resource will have a fixed path + the file name. I don't think this will be the case, I believe the files will be stored in google drive.

I could set up an SVN repository on my machine, which would ease the process of sending him files, however the embedded links problem remains.

Any ideas or thoughts on how to simplify this process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use GitHub repo to host the resources (I'd put raw data github links into the script). This would allow cooperation during development. There's no way to have some code generate URL's for resources dynamically, you need to populate them manually or using a script.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, the problem is that I can't be trusted to edit the resources myself. So it's not as much a 'collaboration' but rather a single security node that everything must pass through. Check out what I answered to @YoavGlazner

Comment: Then use gerrit code review. That requires normal contributors to pass all their commits through review process.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good option

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a file-hosting service can help:

You friend will setup up for example a Shared Google Drive folder with you.
You will place your resources in his folder and get the links!

Other hosting services might give you better permission granularity than Google Drive so be sure to check it out...

Comment: Then the problem is that the resource remains with the option to edit, so from his perspective, I could add a legitimate resource and later edit it to be malicious.

Comment: @g3trans - He can change the permissions of of the resource after approval

Comment: I wish there was a "Add but not edit" option for any of these cloud drives. We'll find a way to make it work. Thanks